# Extract the elemets of a list and add to a df R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe, **`mac_address`** and **`sensor`** are device ids and **`stay`** is a list of numbers that is repeated if the mac_address and sensor are the same.

```
> str(params_df1)
'data.frame':   189 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ mac_address: Factor w/ 21 levels "00:00:00:00:00:00",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ sensor     : Factor w/ 9 levels "2_5","3_2","2_6",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ stay       :List of 189

>head(df)
mac_address          sensor  stay  
1 00:00:00:00:00:00    2_5  1, 1        
2 00:00:00:00:00:00    2_5  1, 1        
3 00:00:00:00:AA:AA    2_1  2, 4, 7     
4 00:00:00:00:AA:AA    2_1  2, 4, 7     
5 00:00:00:00:AA:AA    2_1  2, 4, 7     
6 00:00:00:B2:30:DB    2_2  2, 2        
7 00:00:00:B2:30:DB    2_2  2, 2        
8 00:00:00:B2:30:DB    2_6  4, 8, 6, 7  
9 00:00:00:B2:30:DB    2_6  4, 8, 6, 7  
9 00:00:00:B2:30:DB    2_6  4, 8, 6, 7  
9 00:00:00:B2:30:DB    2_6  4, 8, 6, 7  

> dput(droplevels(df2[19:30, ]))
structure(list(mac_address = c("00:00:00:00:00:3D", "00:00:00:00:00:3D", 
"00:00:00:00:00:3D", "00:00:00:00:00:3D", "00:00:00:00:00:3D", 
"00:00:00:00:00:3D", "00:00:00:00:00:3D", "00:00:00:00:00:3D", 
"00:00:00:00:01:00", "00:00:00:00:01:00", "00:00:00:00:01:00", 
"00:00:00:00:01:00"), sensor = c("2_6", "2_6", "2_6", "2_6", 
"2_6", "2_6", "2_6", "2_6", "3_1", "3_1", "3_1", "3_1"), stay = list(
    c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), c(1, 
    1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), c(1, 1, 
    2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), c(1, 1, 2, 
    2, 3, 3, 3, 3), c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), c(1, 2, 1, 2), 
    c(1, 2, 1, 2), c(1, 2, 1, 2), c(1, 2, 1, 2))), row.names = 19:30, class = "data.frame")
```

I include the **droplevels** with other example, but I don't think it's necessary

I want to separate the list in this way, so that the first item on the **`list`** corresponds to the first, the second to the second, and so on, so it would look like this.

```
>head(df)
mac_address          sensor  stay      cluster
1 00:00:00:00:00:00    2_5  1, 1        1
2 00:00:00:00:00:00    2_5  1, 1        1
3 00:00:00:00:AA:AA    2_1  2, 4, 7     2
4 00:00:00:00:AA:AA    2_1  2, 4, 7     4
5 00:00:00:00:AA:AA    2_1  2, 4, 7     7
6 00:00:00:B2:30:DB    2_2  2, 2        2
7 00:00:00:B2:30:DB    2_2  2, 2        2
8 00:00:00:B2:30:DB    2_6  4, 8, 6, 7  4
9 00:00:00:B2:30:DB    2_6  4, 8, 6, 7  8
9 00:00:00:B2:30:DB    2_6  4, 8, 6, 7  6
9 00:00:00:B2:30:DB    2_6  4, 8, 6, 7  7
```

Comment: Could you please share your data in a copy/pasteable way? `dput(droplevels(df[1:10, ]))` would be great.

Comment: @GregorThomas Have you found it's important to include `droplevels`? Asking in case I should include that in similar situations.

Comment: Yes, of course, I'll give you 19 to 30, instead of 1 to 10, which is a more illustrative example

Comment: @GregorThomas this should be enough to give an answer `dat <- data.frame(mac=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9))` and 
`dat$stay <- list(c(1,1),c(1, 1),c(2, 4, 7),c(2, 4, 7),c(2, 4, 7),c(2, 2),c(2, 2),c(4, 8, 6, 7),c(4, 8, 6, 7),c(4, 8, 6, 7) ,c(4, 8, 6, 7))`

Comment: `droplevels` is needed if the data has a factor with a lot of levels. Here we can see from the `str` that  OP's `mac_address` is a factor with 21 levels. Getting all of them probably wouldn't be tooooo long, but it's more than we need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(mac_address, sensor) %>%
  mutate(cluster = unlist(first(stay)))
# # A tibble: 12 x 4
# # Groups:   mac_address [2]
#    mac_address       sensor stay      cluster
#    <chr>             <chr>  <list>      <dbl>
#  1 00:00:00:00:00:3D 2_6    <dbl [8]>       1
#  2 00:00:00:00:00:3D 2_6    <dbl [8]>       1
#  3 00:00:00:00:00:3D 2_6    <dbl [8]>       2
#  4 00:00:00:00:00:3D 2_6    <dbl [8]>       2
#  5 00:00:00:00:00:3D 2_6    <dbl [8]>       3
#  6 00:00:00:00:00:3D 2_6    <dbl [8]>       3
#  7 00:00:00:00:00:3D 2_6    <dbl [8]>       3
#  8 00:00:00:00:00:3D 2_6    <dbl [8]>       3
#  9 00:00:00:00:01:00 3_1    <dbl [4]>       1
# 10 00:00:00:00:01:00 3_1    <dbl [4]>       2
# 11 00:00:00:00:01:00 3_1    <dbl [4]>       1
# 12 00:00:00:00:01:00 3_1    <dbl [4]>       2
```

This works because you already have the right number of rows per MAC address. If you had one row per MAC address the solution would actually be simpler, because the `tidyr::unnest` function does exactly what you want from that starting point---`tidyr::unnest(df_short, cluster)` would have done it.

Comment: I get the following error: Error: Column `cluster` must be length 18 (the group size) or one, not 2

Comment: And I think that in the solution that you have post, you only have a count the `mac_address`, but also the `sensor`is necesary, as I put in the example above

Comment: Ah, I thought `mac_addreess` and `sensor` were encoding the same information. If they vary differently then yes, put both in the `group_by` (answer edited).